# ElasticSearch LIKE query using wildcard

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Something similar i am trying to achieve for below JSON.

SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ORGID = "BACKENDORG" AND TYPE = "AUDIT" AND
(sessionId LIKE '%16ECA064B298356B%' OR loginUserId LIKE '%16ECA064B298356B%' OR txnId LIKE '%16ECA064B298356B%');

```
{
  "sessionId": "16ECA064B298356B",
  "message": "2019-12-03T05:29:13.217Z [http-nio-8080-exec-4] INFO  http-nio-8080-exec-4 QueryController backendorg 16CFAFCCFB14D9A3 16ECA064B298356B 16ECA3A4EFA026BF 
  "type": "audit",
  "orgId": "backendorg",
  "loginUserId": "16CFAFCCFB14D9A3",
  "txnId": "16ECA3A4EFA026BF"
 }
```

trying to write a LIKE query using BoolQueryBuilder, Here is my query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "orgId": {
              "value": "backendorg",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "type": {
              "value": "audit",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "sessionId": {
                    "wildcard": "16ECA064B298356B",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "loginUserId": {
                    "wildcard": "16ECA064B298356B",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "wildcard": {
                  "txnId": {
                    "wildcard": "16ECA064B298356B",
                    "boost": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "minimum_should_match": "1",
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Above query should return the above JSON result, but it showing zero hits.
It would be helpful if someone pointed out the issue.

Comment: What's the type of your sessionId, a text or keyword, if it's text try to lower case "16ECA064B298356B" in your query

Comment: it is a text. Let me try and will get back to you.